# Anonymous method inside hash assignment

Tags: ruby, anonymous-function

Is there anything like this possible in Ruby:

hash = { :foo => 'bar', :bar => lambda{ *condition* ? return 'value1' : return 'value2'}}

That actual code doesn't work (clearly), and I know I could just do the logic before the hash assignment, but it would be nice to work inside the assignment like this. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a lambda for that, just this should work:

```
hash = {
    :foo => 'bar',
    :bar => condition ? 'value1' : 'value2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to use a function result on hash,

```
hash= {
    :foo=> 'foooooo',
    :bar=> lambda {
        if condition
            value1
        else
            value2
        end
    }.call
}
```